# Removed right margin on desktop view

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I need a menu at the right. it works fine in mobile view keep aligned in left and leaving space in the right. But I require the result as opposite in desktop. menu need to aligned right and left side can be white space. how to achieve this?

here is my code : `mr-auto` works fine with mobile. how to apply only on mobile?

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">English</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">French</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">German</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Doutch</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Michel Pienazak</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what do you mean with *aligned*? You want the text on the left, or the whole container just on the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class="float-md-left"` will make an element float left but only on md size and up.

The same can be done with margins, you can add a breakpoint modifier `{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}`

See here: 
[Floats](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/#notation) [Margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/float/#responsive)